# What is the difference between Real Analysis, Mathematical Analysis, Functional Analysis, and Calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

What is the difference between Real Analysis, Mathematical Analysis, Functional Analysis, and Calculus?

And is Analysis is the general field to all of them?

Comment: And is Analysis is the general field to all of them?

Comment: You can use Wikipedia?

Comment: As a rough description, calculus is what you do in high school and introductory college (few proofs, formulas, rules for derivatives, integrals, limits etc), mathematical analysis is usually the $\epsilon-\delta$ calculus or calculus with proofs and some theory (eg baby Rudin), real analysis starts from measure theory and can go very very deep into BMO spaces etc, functional analysis is operators on infinite dimensional spaces (so a generalization of linear algebra to spaces of functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Mathematical" in "Mathematical analysis" is just to distinguish this from non-mathematical uses of the term "analysis".  The basic branches are

1. "Real analysis": generally concerned with functions of one or more real variables, and measures
2. "Complex analysis": generally concerned with analytic or harmonic functions of one or more complex variables
3. "Functional analysis": generally concerned with various spaces which have both algebraic and topological structures, in particular various types of topological vector spaces, usually infinite-dimensional.

"Calculus" is not much seen these days outside of undergraduate courses.

Comment: I think of analysis as that part of mathematics that grew out of the limit concept. That starts first with calculus, and then as time has moved on, has sprouted tributaries, e.g. real, complex, harmonic, functional ... analysis.

Comment: When Poincaré invented modern topology he called it *analysis situs*.